# L-sentences and spectra

Tags: logic, model-theory

Is there an example of a sentence with spectrum {p|p is prime}?

I may need to resort to some theorem of Algebra, but not sure if it will help.

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Yes, I believe there is, though I won't claim to be able to show it.

I'm not very knowledgeable about the subject, but from I gather, there is a full characterization of first-order spectra in terms of complexity of characteristic functions. It says that spectra are exactly the sets decidable by a non-deterministic Turing machine in $O(2^{cx})$ time, where $c$ is (any) constant; in particular, any set decidable in polynomial time is a spectrum. Due to AKS, this includes the set of prime numbers.

To read more on the subject, see [this survey on arXiv](http://arxiv.org/abs/0907.5495) or [this monograph on Mostowski](http://books.google.pl/books?id=Ri4kjs-iGRgC&pg=PA269), or [the paper containing the original result (behind a paywall)](http://www.jstor.org/discover/10.2307/2272354?uid=3738840&uid=2&uid=4&sid=21101841040411).